# Mountain bike tires for rocky, steep, dirt trails?

Tags: tire, mountain-bike, regional, us

I live in central Iowa and travel once a year to the Breck area (Breckenridge, CO) to do mountain biking. Since that is the Rocky Mountains, well they are rocky and steep. Very different terrain from the dirt top soil trails here in Iowa.

Anyone have some tires they would recommend for the trails out in Colorado? Btw, I ride a 29er.

Comment: What kind of bike do you ride? What kind of trails are you headed for? Cross Country? Downhill? What tires do you currently run? 29'er, I'm guessing cross country hardtail. Let us know.

Comment: "they are rocky and steep."

Comment: Cross country... well in Breck/Summit County it is up country and down country, but more traditional single track albeit rocky single track. It is a xc hard tail - 2010 Stumpjumper. I currently have S-Works Fast Trak LK and that is because those were stock. Only ridden the bike about 30 times. Last season was cut short because I broke my clavicle going off a jump last October.

Comment: @rsecca - Welcome to Bicycles.SE. This question is fine, but it will be applicable to more people if you ask about tires for specific trail conditions, rather than a specific area. (People not familiar with the area may simple skip over the question, when they have knowledge of these types of trails.)

Comment: @ChrisW: WHy would you edit the title to radically change the meaning of the question? Neil didn't choose to do so, and the OP had the option to follow Neil's advice or not. Is it accepted practice for you to do that? For the record, it would irritate me greatly if it was my question. My first instinct was to simply change it back, but that would be as bad as you doing it to begin with.

Comment: @zenbike Talking about the forum (or any other topics, except answering the original question) really belongs instead [on the meta-forum](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/) or [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/bicycles).

Comment: Except here is where the action took place, so here is where I questioned it. How about you answer it?

Comment: @zenbike - I tried to make the question less exclusive, so avoid its being "too localized". I deliberately didn't "radically change" it (what I did was select into the title different words, adjectives and common nouns instead of the proper place name, from the OP's existing question text). The question text is the same. Perhaps the title will be more popular and accessible while still being an accurate summary. See also [How much should editors re-write questions?](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/318/how-much-should-editors-re-write-questions/322#322)

Comment: And how does one attract the attention of the person from whom you wish an answer, if you can't discuss it where it occurs?

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I have been to Breckenridge, however, from what I remember of the terrain and trails it is 'rocky'. I am not sure that I would like to get caught out on punctures there - this will matter whether you are going into true back-country or finding your way around on resort cycle paths.

My recommendation is for the Specialized 'lightweight' 'Armadillo' tyres '[Captain Elite](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCEqProduct.jsp?spid=57266)' - dual compound, nice and nobbly, good TPI casing, foldable - the wishlist boxes get ticked for where you are riding and what you plan to be doing (that'll mean no mud, then).

For the front you can put the 2.2" and on the back the 2.0", and in 29-er.

Anyway, I am quite envious - I wish I had got my act together and had the dream to head off to Colorado for cycling this summer! Enjoy, I am sure you will.

Comment: I will definitely be in back country - bear bell country. I do want something durable and that will climb well on lose dry dirt, dead pine needles, and rocks. My current tires (S-Works Fast Trak LK) just never felt like they would hook up last year. I played with different tire pressures and nothing seemed to help.

Answer (score 1):

See the Schwalbe [Rocket Ron](http://www.schwalbe.com/gbl/en/produkte/mtb/produkt/?ID_Produktgruppe=41&ID_Produkt=175). 29x2.25, good, fast rolling knobby with enough width to be stable in the rock garden, and comfy, good cornering feel, and good hook up. It even sheds mud well. i ride it in Pacific Northwest singletrack, including Whistler and Banff, which is fairly similar to Colorado, if not quite as dry.

Answer (score 1):

> I do want something durable and that will climb well on lose dry dirt, dead pine needles, and rocks. My current tires (S-Works Fast Trak LK) just never felt like they would hook up last year. I played with different tire pressures and nothing seemed to help.

Climbing "well" on loose dry dirt and dead pine needles (not to mention rocks) might be a tall order for a tire.

If you haven't already, perhaps adjusting your riding style might also help: see for example [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-can-i-pedal-in-circles/200#200).

Answer (score 0):

As follow up I wanted to share the tires I wound up riding.

For the front tire I chose a Michelin "Wild Rac'r" 29 x 2.1. Nice low profile lugs in the center for speed on the straights, but beefy side lugs for cornering. Worked great on the rocky soil.

On the back I put a Specialized "The Captain" S-Works 29 x 2.0. It has nicely spaced lugs that hook up wonderfully for rocky climbs, but is not a gigantic tire to keep the wheels rolling fast on level single track. Considering the extreme rockiness and steepness of the trails in the Breckenridge, Colorado area I rode, these tires worked perfectly.

Pressure wise, I ran the front at 40 psi and the back at 35 psi.

[Wild Rac'r](http://www.michelinbicycletire.com/michelinbicycle/index.cfm?event=wildracer29.view)

[The Captain](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCEqProduct.jsp?spid=58032)